# Объединить несколько html страниц в одну pdf-ку с помощью NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer, webcrawler

Всем привет !

С помощью [Crawlee](https://crawlee.dev/docs/examples/capture-screenshot) собрал несколько html-страниц своего сайта и теперь хочется объединить их в одну pdf-ку и хотелось бы узнать какие инструменты для этого есть ? (видел пока только html-pdf-node, но там не очень понял как [все сохранять в одну пдфку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002120/how-to-generate-multiple-pdfs-using-html-pdf-node) и еще там объединяют в примерах несколько pdf файлов, а хочется несколько html страниц)

Comment: Или объединить несколько html файлов в один, но тут тоже хотел бы получить совет по библиотеке которая это может умно сделать (чтобы не было DOCTYPE в начале и подобных моментов)

Comment: вряд ли, что-то такое будет тут уж прото ручками, если вам не очень хочется заморачиваться, объедините все файлы в один, откройте в браузере выберите печать в pdf должно сработать, если нужно что-то аккуратнее - придется разбираться с существующими либами, но автоматом из html файлов pdf вряд ли какая собирает.